# Auto-resize guest display greyed out. Insert Guest Additions fails... Virtual Box VM (Guest: Ubuntu Budgie, Host: Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, guest-additions

I've searched all over the internet for a solution to this and cannot find anything that works.
Here's what I've tried:

- installing guest additions via terminal in vm.
- Swapping video adapter VMSVGA to all other options
- Re-attached VBoxGuestAdditions.iso in Storage settings

I've tried other things, but I can't remember everything I've tried. Any tips are much appreciated because I also can't seem to get my laptop to Dual boot so I figured the VBox would be an easier method to get a linux environment to work in.

[image: Popup error]

```
Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).


Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

Comment: First ensure the virtual CD is empty in the VM settings. Then boot up the VM and click on Devices - there's a good chance you already have there option `Insert the Guest Additions CD Image`. If not, go to `Optical Drives` -> `Choose a Disk File` and browse to the iso.

Comment: The iso is already selected in Optical Drives. I switched it to the ubuntu budgie iso and that also didn't work so I switched it back to VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. Auto-resize guest display is still greyed out and "Insert Guest Additions CD Image..." still caused that popup error.

Comment: I might've explained it bad. 1) Remove any image that you see in Devices / Optical drives in the virtual drive 2) Power down the VM 3) Go to VM settings and remove any .iso image that might be inserted in the optical drive 4) Power up the VM - that's when the the options above should be available. You've already installed the OS, so no point fooling around with Budgie .iso anymore at any point. The error `VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED` means it can't be mounted because the system thinks it's in use.

Comment: Thank you! That resolved the error popu, but the resize display option is still greyed out after "Insert Guest Additions..."

Comment: Don't worry, the first time is always awkward :-) Power the VM down again. Check that you have also the VBox Extension Pack (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) installed. That should do it.

Comment: I made a new answer, see if that resolves the situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove any image that you see in Devices / Optical drives in the
   virtual drive
2. Power down the VM
3. Ensure that [VBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is installed
4. Go to VM settings and remove any .iso image that might be inserted
   in the optical drive
5. Power up the VM

Now when you click Devices -menu, `Insert Guest Additions CD Image...` option should already be available. If not, click Optical Drives -> Choose Disk File and browse to the .iso image.

If it doesn't install automatically, open terminal and navigate to the cdrom. The mount point depends on the OS, for example Debian-based distros mount it often to /media, OpenSUSE /run/media/$USER/. Execute `sudo VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. That should take care of it.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I've been unable to get dual boot to work so I'm trying to get VBox working. I'm sorry for not clarifying, I'm simply saying I need to figure this out because dual boot is also giving me trouble.